# Can't toggle class (dropdown) by clicking in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I was trying to create a dropdown list, it works in CodePen.io but not in WordPress (I'm using plugin which is Wow Plugin: WP Coder v2.3.2)

When I press the dropdown list, it just changes its background color. The list doesn't come out at all.

html code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="select">
          <span>選擇目的地</span>
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="destination">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li id="US">美國</li>
          <li id="UK">英國</li>
          <li id="JP">日本</li>
          <li id="KR">韓國</li>
          <li id="SG">新加坡</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(300);
    });
    $('.dropdown').focusout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideUp(300);
    });
    $('.dropdown .dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('span').text($(this).text());
        $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('input').attr('value', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As my question can't place too many code, so I put css code here.

css code:

```
* {
  outline: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
body {
  background-color: #fafafa
}
span.msg,
span.choose {
  color: #555;
  padding: 5px 0 10px;
  display: inherit
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  text-align: center
}

.dropdown {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(204, 204, 204);
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #474747;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left
}
.dropdown .select {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px
}
.dropdown .select > i {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    float: right;
    line-height: 20px
}
.dropdown:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(204, 204, 204)
}
.dropdown:active {
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}
.dropdown.active:hover,
.dropdown.active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}
.dropdown.active .select > i {
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 0 1px 5px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    max-height: 144px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 9
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer
} 
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:active {
    background-color: #e2e2e2
}
```